# Creating hex string parameter in query string

Tags: php, bash, sha

I need to create a query string with the following structure:
https://api.company.com/api/hello.json?app_id=$name&hash=$hash

The $hash variable should be the SHA1 has of the current challenge string concatenated with my client secret.

I've tested my api credentials in the console by running the following bash script (which gives me the correct response)

```
$ challenge=$(curl -s "http://www.company.com/api/hello.json?app_id=$name" | head -1 | sed 's/.*"challenge": *"\([0-9]*\)".*/\1/')
$ hash=$(printf $challenge$key | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed 's/^.*\([a-f0-9]\{40\}\).*$/\1/')
$ curl "http://www.company.com/api/hello.json?app_id=$name&hash=$hash"
```

However when I try to recreate the $hash variable programmatically with PHP the authentication fails due to incorrect hash parameter.

To create the $hash parameter I use:

```
$hash = sha1($challenge . $key);
```

But obviously I'm missing something here. I assume the expression in the bash script:

```
a-f0-9]\{40\}\).*$/\1/
```

checks if the string is a 40 characters hexadecimal string, but I'm not sure how to integrate this in my PHP code.

If I check the value of $challenge variable in the console I ge ta 9 digit numeric value like : 244971205 whereas the same variable in my PHP script has a string value. Could this be the reason why my $hash parameter do not get properly formatted?

Worth noting that if I use the $hash variable value I get by running

```
echo "$hash"
```

in the console directly in my query string the api call succeeds, but I want to get the same value programmatically.

Would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Check your inputs. Are you sure PHP's $challenge and $key are identical to the ones from command line? `var_export()` can help.

Comment: I believe so, but will double check. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If I check the value of $challenge in the console I ge ta 9 digit numeric value like : 244971205 whereas the same variable in my PHP script has a string value.

Comment: I seem to get the same result when using your `printf | openssl dgst | sed` method as I do with `sha1($challenge . $key)`, even when using mixtures of ints and numeric strings. Are you certain that `$challenge` and `$key` are identical between the two?

Comment: I noticed that If if check the value of $challenge variable in the console I get a 9 digit numeric value like : 244971205 whereas the same variable in my PHP script has a string value so seem like I'm missing an important step here.

Comment: Is the string value in your php script equal to the numeric value you get on the command line? If not can you post the php code that you use to generate `$challenge`?

Comment: Like this :  $challenge = "https://api.company.com/api/list.json?app_id=$partner"

Comment: Which is obviously wrong since this return a text string value instead of a numeric 9 digit value. I assume I need to extract the numeric value with a regex expression but not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I was overcomplicating things. What I actually needed to do in order to get the correct value for the `$challenge` variable was to parse the JSON data with `json_decode` and after that just access the property that held the numeric value like this `$challenge = $obj['object']['property']`